# DynamicData: TransformToTree

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I have an application where tags can be structured in a hierarchy by using a backslash (\) character.

for example;

```
Country\Canada\Alberta
Country\Canada\British Columbia
Country\USA\California
Country\USA\Texas
```

would become in the user interface;

```
Country
    Canada
        Alberta
        British Columbia
    USA
        California
        Texas
```

In the database it is stored as a string and returned to the client as a `TagDto`. I have tried the following to accomplish this;

```
public class TagDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TagLeaf
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public string ParentId { get; }
    public int TagId { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public TagLeaf(string id, string parentId, int tagId, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        ParentId = parentId;
        TagId = tagId;
        Name = name;
    }

    // IEquatable implemented on Id property.
}

public class TagsViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private IDisposable TagsSubscription { get; }

    public SourceCache<TagDto, string> Tags { get } = new SourceCache<TagDto, string>(t => t.Id);

    private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TagLeafViewModel> _tagTree;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TagLeafViewModel> TagTree => _tagTree;

    public ReactiveCommand AddBelgium { get; }

    public TagsViewModel()
    {
        AddBelgium = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => 
            Tags.AddOrUpdate(new TagDto {Id = 5, Name = @"Country\Belgium"});

        // this comes from an web service normally. 
        Tags.AddOrUpdate(new[] {
            new TagDto {Id = 1, Name = @"Country\Canada\Alberta"},
            new TagDto {Id = 2, Name = @"Country\Canada\British Columbia"},
            new TagDto {Id = 3, Name = @"Country\USA\California"},
            new TagDto {Id = 4, Name = @"Country\USA\Texas"}
        });

        TagsSubscription = Tags
            .Connect()
            .TransformMany(dto => 
            {
                var names = dto.Name.Split(new[] {'\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var results = new TagLeaf[names.Length];
                var parentId = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                    var name = names[i];
                    var id = $"{parentId}{name}\\";
                    results[i] = new TagLeaf(id, parentId, dto.Id, name);
                    parentId = id;
                }

                return results;
            }, leaf => leaf.Id)
            .TransformToTree(leaf => leaf.ParentId)
            .Transform(leaf => new TagLeafViewModel(leaf))
            .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<TagLeafViewModel>.Ascending(vm => vm.Name))
            .Bind(out _tagTree)
            .Subscribe();
    }
}

public class TagLeafViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TagLeafViewModel> _children;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TagLeafViewModel> Children => _children;

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value);
    }

    public TagLeafViewModel(Node<TagLeaf, string> node)
    {
        Name = node.Item.Name;
        ChildrenSubscription = node.Children
            .Connect()
            .Transform(n => new TagLeafViewModel(n))
            .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<TagLeafViewModel>.Ascending(vm => vm.Name))
            .Bind(out _children)
            .Subscribe();
    }
}

// TagsView.xaml
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="AddBelgiumButton" Content="Add Belgium"/>
    <telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="TagTreeView">
        <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadtreeView>
</StackPanel>

// TagsView.xaml.cs constructor
public TagsView()
{
    ...
    this.WhenActivated(d => 
    {
        d(this.AddBelgiumButton.Events().Click.Select(x => Unit.Default).InvokeCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.AddBelgium));
        d(this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.TagTree, v => v.TagTreeView.ItemsSource));
    });
}
```

This produces a tree as I would expect, however if I expand `Country` and click *Add Belgium*, instead of seeing this insert into the tree as a new node underneath country - it collapses the whole country node.

Adding the new tag results in 2 new `TagLeaf`'s being streamed into `TramsformToTree`. One for Country and one for Belgium so I understand why it's updating the country node but, I am not sure how I can overcome that - any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for us to help you.

Comment: You're right, it was a little vague. I hope this is better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've made a breakthrough however, suggestions are still welcome.

Realizing that `TransformMany` was the problem in my earlier attempt, I decided it would be necessary to maintain 2 separate caches to achieve what I was after.

I now have a TagService which exposes both caches. Whenever an item is changed in the underlying `TagDto` cache I manually update the `TagLeaf` cache with the changes. In my sample application this now inserts the new node without collapsing the root node.

This is incomplete, I still need to handle removing the parent `TagLeaf` when they have no children in the `TagLeaf` cache but I believe I can make that work so I consider problem solved.

```
public class TagService : ITagService
{
    private readonly SourceCache<TagDto, int> _tagDtos = new SourceCache<TagDto, int>(t => t.Id);
    public IObservableCache<TagDto, int> TagDtos => _tagDtos;

    private readonly SourceCache<TagLeaf, string> _tagLeafs = new SourceCache<TagLeaf, string>(t => t.Id);
    public IObservableCache<TagLeaf, string> TagLeafs => _tagLeafs;

    public TagService()
    {
        _tagDtos.AddOrUpdate(new[]
        {
            new TagDto {Id = 1, Name = @"Country\Canada\Alberta"},
            new TagDto {Id = 2, Name = @"Country\Canada\British Columbia"},
            new TagDto {Id = 3, Name = @"Country\USA\California"},
            new TagDto {Id = 4, Name = @"Country\USA\Texas"}
        });

        _tagDtos
            .Connect()
            .Transform(dto =>
            {
                var names = dto.Name.Split(new[] {'\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var results = new TagLeaf[names.Length];

                var parentId = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                    var name = names[i];
                    var id = $"{parentId}{name}\\";
                    results[i] = new TagLeaf(id, parentId, dto.Id, name);
                    parentId = id;
                }

                return new TagBranch(dto.Id, results);
            })
            .ForEachChange(change =>
            {
                var branch = change.Current;
                switch (change.Reason)
                {
                    case ChangeReason.Remove:
                        var lastLeaf = branch.Leaves.Last();
                        _tagLeafs.RemoveKey(lastLeaf.Id);
                        break;

                    case ChangeReason.Add:
                        foreach (var leaf in branch.Leaves)
                        {
                            if (_tagLeafs.Keys.Contains(leaf.Id))
                                continue;

                            _tagLeafs.AddOrUpdate(leaf);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            })
            .Subscribe();
    }

    public void AddOrUpdate(TagDto dto)
    {
        _tagDtos.AddOrUpdate(dto);
    }
}
```

The constructor in TagsViewModel now looks like this;

```
public TagsViewModel(ITagService tagService)
{
    AddBelgium = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        tagService.AddOrUpdate(new TagDto {Id = 5, Name = @"Country\Belgium"}));

    TagsSubscription = tagService.TagLeafs
        .Connect()
        .TransformToTree(leaf => leaf.ParentId)
        .Transform(node => new TagLeafViewModel(node))
        .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<TagLeafViewModel>.Ascending(vm => vm.Name))
        .Bind(out _tagTree)
        .Subscribe();
}
```